# Salt top.sls does not update on `salt-run fileserver.update` with gitfs

Tags: git, configuration-management, saltstack

I have a single salt minion connected to the salt master. I recently renamed a large .sls from 'webserver.sls' to 'jetty.sls'. I use a gitfs backend with pygit2 and ssh. I have only enabled the gitfs backend. 
`/etc/salt/master`:

```
fileserver_backend:
#  - roots
  - git

gitfs_provider: pygit2
gitfs_remotes:
  - git@bitbucket.org:Groomblecom/[repo].git:
    - pubkey: /root/salt-credentials/id_rsa.pub
    - privkey: /root/salt-credentials/id_rsa
```

However, whenever I run `salt-run fileserver.update && salt '*' state.highstate` I get an error:

```
Data failed to compile:
----------
    No matching sls found for 'webserver' in env 'base'
```

Running `salt '*' state.show_sls jetty` gives expected (long) output, consistent with what I see in the bitbucket repo. Running `salt '*' state.show_top` gives the following:

```
----------
    base:
        - common
        - ingress
        - webserver
```

This is inconsistent with the top.sls in the bitbucket repo:

```
base:
  '*':
    - common
  '*ingress*':
    - ingress
    - jetty
    - nginx
```

Running `salt-run fileserver.update` or `rm -rf /var/cache/salt/* && service salt-master restart` has no impact on the outputs.

I would like to know if there is a known bug (and workaround) for this behavior, if there is a way to force a real cache clear, or if I have made a configuration mistake.

Comment: Since I cannot answer my own question with 1 rep, I'll just put this here:

The solution is that salt considers all branches, then merges _all_ (!) branches to compile the final SLS (kinda. I'm still not quiiiite sure what the logic is). I had an old branch which was a couple commits behind master, and so still referenced webserver.sls. The solution was pretty simple: I just added the following to /etc/salt/master: `gitfs_env_whitelist:` `  - master` (the second being it's own line immediately after the first. If anyone wants to post this as an answer for better visibility, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that salt considers all branches, then merges all (!) branches to compile the final top.sls. I had an old branch which was a couple commits behind master, and so still referenced webserver.sls. 
The solution is pretty simple: just add the following to `/etc/salt/master`:

```
gitfs_env_whitelist:
  - master
```

Or, if your primary branch isn't master, replace master with your branch name.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that salt merges all branches to compile the final top.sls. I was able to fix it by adding this to `/etc/salt/master`:

```
gitfs_env_whitelist:
  - base
```

Since Salt maps the `master` branch to the `base` environment (thanks to `gitfs_base`), the correct `env` to whitelist is `base`, not `master`.